# Vector Layer with WFS protocol

Tags: vector, gis, openlayers, geoserver

is it a must to use BBOX strategy with WFS protocol in Vector layers ?

I cannot display this layer without BBOX strategy:

```
vLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Test", { 

    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({ 
        "default": style 
    }), 
      maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180, -90, 180, 90).transform(geographic,mercator), 
      sphericalMercator: true,   
      protocol:  new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({   
      url: 'http://myDomain/geoserver/wfs', 
      featureType: "Layer_1",   
      featureNS: "http://mapmap.org", 
      srsName: "EPSG:3857", 
      version: "1.1.0", 
      extractAttributes: true, 
      isBaseLayer: false, 

        }) 
      });
```

I am not getting any request in firebug.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed? 
That should request your data once and will not do anything on a change of either zoom or bounds.

BTW: You have a dangling-comma error (`isBaseLayer: false,`) but that is most probably not too relevant.

Comment: yes I tried Fixed strategy but it is not working for me! I don't know where is the problem, I got nothing displays on the map. There is a request in firebug with right response but nothing is shown on the map.